# Ajax post to Flask - json

Tags: ajax, flask

I've got a google-maps lookup with autocomplete on the client side - I'm trying to transfer the "place" object over to the server once the user selects it - I could parse it down client-side, but I figured it's easier to do server-side.  I verified from the browser 'network' inspect that it is sending over the correct json object, but server side I can't get the right object.  I've tried every permutation of request.* that I can find and either get None or a `<module 'flask.json'>` which I know isn't right.

Code:

```
function sendplace() {
    $('placebutton').click(function() {
        var add1 = place;
        console.log(place);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/new_place2',
            data: JSON.stringify(place),
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
```

and server-side:

```
@app.route('/new_place2', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_place2():
    place = request.form.get('place')
    print "address: ", place
    return ("Success, (*&)er!")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `request.get_json()`.  request.form is reserved for the mimetype `application/www-form-urlencoded`.  If `get_json()` doesn't work look at `request.data` and ensure that you can run the following on it:

```
import json

data = json.loads(request.data)
data.get('place')
```

If that doesn't work you probably have a problem with your JSON

Comment: Thanks - spent about two hours this morning looking - found lots of posts but not the one above... 'get_json()' worked.